# Draggable into draggable

Tags: jquery, google-maps, draggable

I'm looking for a way to drag and drop an item into another item draggable too.

html

```
<div id="range">
    <span class="test">test</span>
    <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_Ym3du2sG3R4/TQXJiupb32I/AAAAAAAADCs/KIDut36pOeA/s1600/Green-Nature-with-sunrise-wallpaper.jpeg" id="background" />
</div>
```

js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#background, span.test").draggable(); 
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J8c9P/1/)

The problem as shown in my example is that when I slide the block test at the end of background block, the blackground block does not extend. I'm looking for the same functionality as the drag n drop of a marker in Google maps

Any idea? 
thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

problem is in your css. you should disable *overflow:hidden* in **#range** element.
css:

```
#range {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;

    border:1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

span.test {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;  
    padding: 10px;
    background: white;
    z-index: 9999;
}
#background{
   position: relative;
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
}
```

Result: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/up53sad0/)